# i make react lotto program but not rerender number (use contextAPI)

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I listened to lotto programs using contextAPI. However, pressing the button to dispatch does not render the screen. There's a change in the value of the state, but why... Please help me.

Here are my codes.

```
<LottoArray.js>

import React from "react";
import Item from "./LottoItem";
import Button from "./Button";
import { useStateLotto, useDispatchLotto } from "../context/LottoContext";
import "./lotto.css";

function LottoArray() {
  const state = useStateLotto();
  const dispatch = useDispatchLotto();

  const handleLotto = () => {
    console.log("handleLotto execute!");
    dispatch({
      type: "DROW",
    });
    console.log(
      "handleLtto in num = ",
      state.map((item) => item.num)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="lottoBox">
        {state.map((box) => (
          <Item key={box.index} number={box.num} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button handleLotto={handleLotto} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default LottoArray;
```

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

const LottoBox = [
  {
    index: 1,
    num: "?",
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    num: "?",
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    num: "?",
  },
  {
    index: 4,
    num: "?",
  },
  {
    index: 5,
    num: "?",
  },
  {
    index: 6,
    num: "?",
  },
  {
    index: 7,
    num: "+",
  },
  {
    index: 8,
    num: "?",
  },
];

export function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DROW":
      /* 여기서 랜덤수 생성해서 넣어주자.,.. */
      LottoBox.map((box) =>
        box.index !== 7
          ? (box.num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 45))
          : (box.num = "+")
      );
      console.log("LottoBox in reducer = ", LottoBox);
      return LottoBox;
    default:
      return;
  }
}

const LottoState = createContext();
const LottoDispatch = createContext();

export function LottoProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, LottoBox);
  return (
    <LottoState.Provider value={state}>
      <LottoDispatch.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </LottoDispatch.Provider>
    </LottoState.Provider>
  );
}

export function useStateLotto() {
  return useContext(LottoState);
}

export function useDispatchLotto() {
  return useContext(LottoDispatch);
}
```

If the state of the context API changes, the screen should be re-rendered when dispatching itself, but it doesn't seem to be re-endered anywhere. However, if you take a picture of the value, the state value is saved as the changed value and is recorded in the console.

here is my result

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: You do not return an updated state in your reducer.

Comment: Jacob Smit Thanks to you, I solved it.